# How to create a custom VF page with dynamically generated HTML code?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, pageblocksection, pageblocksectionitem

I'm using a custom rich text field.

The rich text field is created in a standard object.

In the rich text field there is a dynamically generated HTML code via apex.

Here is what the rich text field contains:
[image]

What I need to achieve is to remove the dynamically generated HTML code from the rich text field and place it in a VF page in separate section in the layout of the standard object?

In the standard object I have different sections with VF pages.

Here is an example of a section with VF page:
[image]

I need to achieve the same result as in the above example by adding a separate section with VF page in the standard object where I can put my dynamically generated HTML code via apex.

Please advise if it is feasible and how it can be achieved?

Comment: Feasible? Yes. But extremely insecure. How are you generating this markup? Do you expect it to contain anything besides images?

Comment: @AdrianLarson `How are you generating this markup?` I'm generating this markup via Apex.

Comment: @AdrianLarson `Do you expect it to contain anything besides images?` It is HTML text. There are no images. The generated HTML text is display as table.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  I've included a print screen example of what the HTML text looks like and what I need is to remove the HTML text from the rich text field and put my dynamically generated HTML text into a separate section of the layout block.